# a python program that searches text files and prints out mutual lines

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a python program that takes n number of text files , each file contains names , each name on a separate line like this

```
Steve
Mark
Sarah
```

what the program does is that it prints out only the names that exist in all the inputted files .
I am new to programming so I don't really know how to implement this idea , but I thought in recursion , still the program seems to run in an infinite loop , I am not sure what's the problem . is the implementation wrong ? if so , do you have a better idea of how to implement it ?

```
import sys
arguments = sys.argv[1:]
files = {}

file = iter(arguments)
for number in range(len(sys.argv[1:])):
    files[number] = open(next(file))

def close_files():
    for num in files:
        files[num].close()


def start_next_file(line,files,orderOfFile):
    print('starting next file')
    if orderOfFile < len(files): # to avoid IndexError
        for line_searched in files[orderOfFile]:
            if line_searched.strip():
                line_searched = line_searched[:-1]
                print('searched line = '+line_searched)
                print('searched compared to = ' + line)
                if line_searched == line:
                    #good now see if that name exists in the other files as well
                    start_next_file(line,files,orderOfFile+1) 

    elif orderOfFile >= len(files): # when you finish searching all the files
        print('got ya '+line) #print the name that exists in all the files
        for file in files: 
            # to make sure the cursor is at the beginning of the read files 
            #so we can loop through them again
            files[file].seek(0)



def start_find_match(files):
    orderOfFile = 0
    for line in files[orderOfFile] : 
        # for each name in the file see if it exists in all other files 
        if line.strip():
            line = line[:-1]
            print ('starting line = '+line)
            start_next_file(line,files,orderOfFile+1)



start_find_match(files)
close_files()
```

Comment: Are all your text files in a single directory?

Comment: @Jarad yes, they are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how to fix your code exactly but here's one conceptual way to think about it.

`listdir` gets all the files in the directory as a list. We narrow that to only .txt files. Next, open, read, split on newlines, and lower to make a larger list containing names. So, `files` will be a list of lists.  Last, find the intersection across all lists using some `set` logic.

```
import os

folder = [f for f in os.listdir() if f[-4:] == '.txt']
files = []

for i,file in enumerate(folder):
  with open(file) as f:
    files.append([name.lower() for name in f.read().splitlines()])

result = set.intersection(*map(set, files))
```

Example:

```
#file1.txt
john
smith
mary
sue
pretesh
ashton
olaf
Elsa

#file2.txt
David
Lorenzo
Cassy
Grant
elsa
Felica
Salvador
Candance
Fidel
olaf
Tammi
Pasquale

#file3.txt
Jaleesa
Domenic
Shala
Berry
Pamelia
Kenneth
Georgina
Olaf
Kenton
Milly
Morgan
elsa
```

Returns:

```
{'olaf', 'elsa'}
```